# Script works in Greasemonkey but not Tampermonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I've found a script that works within Greasemonkey on Firefox but doesn't work on Tampermonkey in Chrome. The only thing i've found online to try is changing "unsafewindow" to "window" as it doesnt work in chrome, which didnt work. Beyond that i have no idea and i'd really appreciate some help.

And i've gotta try and fill the wordcount because it wont let me post.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Haggler
// @version     1.1.0
// @namespace   Shinzan
// @Description Neopets autohaggler
// @Match       http://www.neopets.com/haggle.phtml*
// @Match       http://www.neopets.com/haggle.phtml
// @include     http://www.neopets.com/objects.phtml?obj_type=*&type=shop
// @include     http://www.neopets.com/objects.phtml?type=shop&obj_type=*
// @require     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hectorvazc/jsfun/master/jsfun.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var url = document.URL;
var OCR = true;
var return_ab = true;
var haggle_type = 1;

function solve_captcha(url, callback) {
    var captcha = new Image();
    captcha.src = url;
    captcha.onload = function(){
          var width = captcha.width;
          var height = captcha.height;

        var canvas = unsafeWindow.document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = width;
        canvas.height = width;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(captcha, 0, 0);

          var imgData = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
          var lowy = 999;
          var lowx = 999;
          var low = 999;

        for (var x = 0; x < imgData.width; x++){
            for (var y = 0; y < imgData.height; y++){
              var i = x*4+y*4*imgData.width;
            var avg = Math.floor((imgData.data[i]+imgData.data[i+1]+imgData.data[i+2])/3);
            if (avg < low){
                low = avg;
              lowx = x;
              lowy = y;
            }
          }
        }
        callback(lowx, lowy);
    };
}

function smart_haggle(haggle_price){
    var val = new Array(2);

    val[0] = haggle_price.substr(0,1);
    val[1] = haggle_price.substr(1,1);

    var x = 0;
    var end_price = "";

    for(x=0; x<haggle_price.length; x++){
        end_price += val[(x%2)];
    }
    return end_price;
}

function pctr_haggle(haggle_price){
    var randomPer = (Math.floor(((Math.random()*10) + 90))/ 100);
    return Math.floor(parseInt(haggle_price) * randomPer);
}


if(url === 'http://www.neopets.com/haggle.phtml'){

    if(return_ab) js().getNode('input[type="submit"]')[1].click();

}else if(url.includes('objects.phtml')){

  var content = js().getNode('table[align="center"][cellpadding="4"][border="0"]');
  js().here(content).find('tr').each(function(tr){
    js().here(tr).find('td').each(function(td){
      var a = js().here(td).find('a').detach()[0];
      js(a).removeAttribute('onclick');
      js(td).insertFirst(a);
    });
  });

}else if(url.includes('haggle.phtml')){

  var src = js().here('div[align=center]').getNode('img[width="450"][height="150"]');
  var haggle_price = js().getNode('font')[2];
  haggle_price = js().here(haggle_price).getNode('b')[3].innerHTML;
  haggle_price = (haggle_price.match("([0-9-,]+)")[0]).replace(",", "");

  var value = (haggle_type) == 1 ? smart_haggle(haggle_price) : pctr_haggle(haggle_price);
  js().find('input[name=current_offer]').val(value);

  if(OCR){
      solve_captcha(document.querySelector('input[type="image"]').src, function(x, y) {
           setTimeout(function(){
              var haggleform = document.querySelector('form[name="haggleform"]');
              var newInput = document.createElement("input");
              var newInput2 = document.createElement("input");

                 newInput.type="hidden";
                 newInput.name="x";
                 newInput.value=x;
                 haggleform.appendChild(newInput);

                 newInput2.type="hidden";
                 newInput2.name="y";
                 newInput2.value=y;
                 haggleform.appendChild(newInput2);
                 haggleform.submit();
           }, 500);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace the uppercase letters in `@` keys with lowercase.

Comment: Tried this and it still doesn't work unfortunately.